# Create multi tabbed Excel from Text files

Tags: unix

I have 3 text files that are delimted with "~" character. I need to create an excel sheet with 3 tabs for these three text files. Is there a way that I can do it? Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help: http://www.gnumeric.org/download.html

In this source, there is 'ssconvert' tool, which a command line spreadsheet converter.